# JBoss 7 EL for Method without a Parameter

Tags: jsp, jstl, glassfish-3, el, jboss7.x

I'm trying to take a Java EE 6 application which runs fine on GlassFish 3.1.1 and deploy it on JBoss 7.0.2.  I'm running into PropertyNotFound exceptions when I try to navigate to pages due to differences in JBoss EL.  It seems that JBoss EL doesn't allow method expressions to methods without parameters of the form:

```
<c:if test="${bean.calculateX('foo').size() > 0}">
```

In this example JBoss EL thinks the size method is a parameter.  I can get it to work in JBoss by changing it to this:

```
<c:if test="${bean.calculateX('foo')[size] > 0}">
```

But now it won't work in GlassFish.  Is there a compatible way to accomplish this?

Comment: What type is `bean.calculateX('foo')`? A collection?

Comment: Yes, the calculateX method returns a List.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That seems to be an EL evaluation bug on the both servers. There are two very similar bug reports to this: [JBoss AS7-2825](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/AS7-2825) (fixed in 7.1.0) and [Glassfish 17628](http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-17628) (fixed in 3.1.2). Those fixes *might* fix your issue as well. Otherwise it's time to report a new one.

I'd however suggest using the EL `empty` keyword instead. There it is for.

```
<c:if test="${not empty bean.calculateX('foo')}">
```

By the way, I wonder if the `[size]` syntax is valid as per the EL spec to represent a non-getter method. This notation is usually used for dynamic properties.

Comment: Switching to "not empty" instead of "size() > 0" worked in my case.  However, there are theoretically cases where someone might want "size() > 5" in which "not empty" wouldn't work.

Comment: I ran into this issue with other methods with no parameters, but unlike the List.size() method I was the author of the methods so I was able to turn them into properties by prefixing them with "get" and avoid the issue altogether.

Comment: True; the List.size case appears to be easily overcome. However, there are theoretically cases where you'd like to make a method call to a method which doesn't take parameters, there aren't special JSTL functions for it, there aren't special provisions in the EL for it (like empty), and you can't turn it into a property by prefixing it with "get".  Luckily I'm not in that scenario right now!